# How to return the position of a value in a javascript object using a datalist

Tags: javascript, html, object, html-datalist

Upon selecting an option from the `datalist`, I'd expect this javascript code to return the `option` location in the javascript `object`.

Without using `datalist` the code works as expected.

Why doesn't this work?

Can `Javascript` respond to new inputs from `datalist` without some sort of page reload? I'm hoping this doesn't require `PHP`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInputId");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function result() {
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = input.value;
}

myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}

myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
  var q = document.getElementById("location").innerHTML;
  if (e.properties.id == q) {
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.width;
  }

});
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="result()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option>AL</option>
<option>PO</option>
<option>RA</option>
</datalist>

<p>Result:<span id="location"></span></p>
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>
<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Comment: The `myObj.forEach()` loop is running when the page is loaded, not when the user types something into the input field.

Comment: You need to run that code in the event handler.

Comment: I must admit I'm a beginner coder. Can you show me how that works?

Comment: Just put it in the `result()` function.

Comment: OK that makes sense, thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look for the selected element, then assign the values to the right `html` elements:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInputId");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

function result() {
  
  var res = myObj.info.find(({properties}) =>
     properties.id === myInputId.value
  );
  
  /*
  // you can also use .forEach()
  
  var res;
  myObj.info.forEach(e => {
    if(e.properties.id === myInputId.value)
      res = e;
  });
  */
  
  if(res){
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = res.properties.id;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = res.properties.width;
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = res.item;
  }
}

myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}

/*
myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
var q = document.getElementById("location").innerHTML;
  if (e.properties.id == q) {
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.width;
  }
  
});
*/
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="result()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option>AL</option>
<option>PO</option>
<option>RA</option>
</datalist>

<p>Result:<span id="location"></span></p>
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>
<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, can you explain what it's doing? I was hoping to build ontop of my forEach function, you don't recommend using that as a solution?

Comment: it's not doing very much really, `find()` will return the first matching element in the array when `properties.id === myInputId.value` , the `.forEach()` will loop through all the array. Once found, you have your classic `getElementById` to assign the found values to the elements, and putting the `loop` in `result()` will execute it every time you hit `Enter` , if it's outside the `result()` it will be executed only once.

Comment: For my code it turns out I just needed to put `myObj.forEach()` in the `result()` function, but for a general solution I like your answer a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

well just looking at this code: in the result function, myInputId isn't a variable, it looks like it should be input.value instead, or change the input variable name to myInputId, and see if you still have other problems.

EDIT

Ok so your problem is it's not updating the position etc...

Why don't you just put that forEach loop in the result function, the way it is now it seems there's no reason why it *should* update.

Comment: Element IDs are automatically turned into global variables.

Comment: So why add the variable input at the top?

Comment: I'm sure he intended to use `input.value` like you say. But `myInputId.value` also works. Have you tried his snippet? It does correctly put the input into the span.

Comment: That's not the part he's having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to input.value, but like Barmar said it's not the problem.

Comment: Placing the forEach loop inside the result function did indeed work, thanks everyone.